# chinese browser throwing javascript error when preloading image

Tags: javascript

When trying to preload an image with an html-inline script like this:

```
new Image().src="/path/to/image.png";
```

I'm occasionally logging this error:

```
由于出现错误 ffffffff 而导致此项操作无法完成。
 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
```

According to google the chinese translates to:

```
This operation can not be completed due to an error ffffffff
```

I've never seen this error with a non-chinese browser and can't recreate it. Obviously, I haven't given you much to go on, but any insight is appreciated.

thanks

Update:
Yes, I looked up the logged IP (not included here) and it seems to be coming from China.

Comment: Is that a Chinese browser *in China*? Maybe just "Chinese network problems"...? :)

Comment: [Someone](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/problem-active-x-buttons-t668813.html) seems to be getting an English version of this error with a particular Active X control. Are you sure the error is tied to the line of code you've cited? I assume the "ffffffff" error code is supposed to represent "-1", but I'm having a hard time googling for an error code "-1".

Comment: The error contains a file path and line number so I'm pretty sure they're tied. Thanks

Comment: Are your pages utf-8 encoded?

Comment: Agreed, "ffffffff" does seem to be a signed 32-bit hex representation of -1. thanks

Comment: Yes, the pages are utf-8 encoded. thanks

Comment: Is your image path something like `/democracy-now/free-tibet/i-heart-the-dalai-lama.jpg` ?

Comment: Since we don't know what the image is all about (see @nickf's "theory") or what a "chinese browser" is specifically, it could be one of several issues. For instance, the Great Firewall is intermittently and arbitrarily blocking the request, the server is misconfigured or having trouble with some requests, or (ominously...) the image is a lure for serving malware and the content being returned isn't an image. You can inspect the packets with Wireshark and look at what's being returned. That might give an actual clue.

Comment: @JaredFarrish it sounds like he's seeing these messages in his logs, not locally nor anywhere where he could install wireshark, unfortunately.